# How can I make welcome-file-list work with Spring Servlet?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, web.xml

This is the code I have:

```
public class Bootstrap implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        container.getServletRegistration("default").addMapping("/resources/*");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext servletContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        servletContext.register(ServletContextConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                container.addServlet("springDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(servletContext));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

moving on:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = "biz.tugay.booksspringone.controller",
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(Controller.class)
)
public class ServletContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

and web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/welcome</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and my controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("welcome");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

When I deploy my app and navigate to localhost:8080/ I expect **HelloController.welcome** to be called, but it is not.

The method is called only if I explicitly visit **http://localhost:8080/welcome**

How can I fix this?

Comment: perhaps it is easier to register something on / with RequestMapping and have it redirect ?

Comment: @Marged Thanks, that works but it changes the address in the url which I do not like.

Comment: @Marged Well forward: works too but still I wonder why this does not work..

Comment: This is something I can not tell you ;-) Why not wire the same code to /welcome and / ?

Comment: by the way: are you sure that specifying a directory works ? I think not: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnaer/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A welcome file list will find for that file "not a request" you specified in the tag.

so

```
<welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>/welcome</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

will look for the file with criteria you specified in view resolver, so it will going to find following file

```
/WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp
```

Create that file and you will be redirected to welcome.jsp for the home url.